# MySQL Master-Master replication issue

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL 5.7 installed on two servers and I configured both servers' mysqld.cnf file as shown below

Server1 configuration.

```
[mysqld]
bind-address    = 192.168.0.1
server_id           = 1
log_bin             = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log.index
relay_log           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin
relay_log_index     = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.index
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size     = 100M
log_slave_updates   = 1
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 1
```

Server2 configuration.

```
[mysqld]
bind-address    = 192.168.0.2
server_id           = 2
log_bin             = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log.index
relay_log           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin
relay_log_index     = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.index
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size     = 100M
log_slave_updates   = 1
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 2
```

Then when I get the out put from Server1 with the below:

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.000006 |      459 |              |                  |                   |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Then I go to  run and get the output as per below at Server2:

```
mysql> STOP SLAVE;
mysql> CHANGE MASTER TO master_host='192.168.0.1', master_port=3306, 
master_user='replicauser', 
master_password='somestrongpassword', master_log_file='mysql-bin.000006', 
master_log_pos=459;
mysql> START SLAVE;
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.000007 |      154 |              |                  |                   |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

So what is the missing to complete my solution ?

**Edit:**

The missing part was just restart for both servers